# Select nth element from multidimensional JSON array with jq

Tags: json, command-line, data-manipulation, jq

How can I use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq) to transform this array of arrays:

```
[
  [
    "sequence",
    "int"
  ],
  [
    "time",
    "string"
  ],
  ...
]
```

Into an array that contains the first (0) element from every subarray? Meaning to produce output like this:

```
[
    "sequence",
    "time",
    ...
]
```

I was thinking to use `reduce xx as $item (...)` but I didnt manage to come up with anything useful.

Comment: jq is a C program. Why tag as jquery?

Comment: Did you mean jQuery by jq?

Comment: I tried to tag as jq, but now i see that if you do that, SO changes the tag to jquery... you cant actually tag something jq

Comment: @Dreen - For future reference, since [`jq` is defined as a synonym for `jquery`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/synonyms) in Stack Overflow's tag system, it gets changed when you submit the question. I don't have the rights to undo this (@SomeoneReadingThisWhoDoesHaveThisPrivilege - I think it could be done, as the `jq` synonym has never been used) I have fixed you up with a brand new `jq-json-processor` tag instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` filter this way:

```
jq 'map(.[0])'
```

Comment: Now, how to apply string interpolation on the result?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be `jq '[.[][0]]'`

this gives the same result as using `map(.[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **reduce**

```
reduce .[] as $k ( null; . + [$k[0]] )
```